# Recognize image within other image

Tags: pattern-matching, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

I want to get a yes/no answer to the question: If the smaller image is in the bigger one or not? Both of them are screenshot from a game I play. Let's me explain the images a bit since the forums doesn't allow me to post images :(

I have to collect parts to upgrade my unit, the parts are "SMALL IMAGE". In the unit's information screen, which contains 6 images of different parts, this is what I called "LARGE IMAGE".

As for my understanding, it's not deep learning since all of the images are not distorted, tilted or rearranged. I found TensorFlow few days ago it may work, but I think I don't have to train my machine to learn anything for this project. Just simply map the smaller one in a bigger one.

I don' know what kind of code will be fitted with the above conditions. And I also have no preference of language to be used since every algorithm and coding is new to me. I have zero experience in programming, and open up to learn new things.

Comment: Welcome! This is a very general question. Usually we want specific questions, but you are probably OK with the group for asking this in this way. That said, any more specifics you can add about what you need to do will help.

Comment: What's more information needed

Comment: Give more details if you get any further comments asking for them

Comment: OK, thanks for now